# What is the "standard" JQuery treeview that most people use? It seems the most popular plugin isn't supported anymore?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, treeview

I've chosen JQuery as my JavaScript library but now I'm a bit frustrated by the JQuery plugin site...   the site kinda sucks... the plugin area isn't designed very well and I can only find a few treeviews.  The one with the most votes ([link text](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/treeview)) isn't supported anymore.

Can someone please point me to an industrial strength treeview?

Desired Features:

- stable
- async / ajax would be nice
- drag and drop nodes would be nice

I've been delighted so far with JQueryUI--nice design.  But, how come it doesn't come with a standard tree view?

Pete

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know that there is a "standard" single solution for this.  One I've used in the past that just got a major update is jsTree, it got a lot of improvements...it doesn't fit your "stable" requirement because it's in RC status, but that should change soon.

[You can get more info on it here](http://www.jstree.com/) (**it is large though**, make sure it's not overkill for your needs)

There are **certainly other options**, but as I haven't used any of them (and we eventually went to a custom tree since our requirements were very light/specific)...I just can't give any first-hand experience information for the alternatives. I'll it for someone who's actually used them to give some insight.

Also, the jQuery UI Tree is coming, it's currently in the planning stages, you can track it's progress here: http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/Tree

Comment: Thanks for the jsTree suggestion... it's feature rich but there is a hard learning curve.

Comment: its a good find, i was looking for something like this. I will surely try it out

Comment: jsTree is probably one of the best, once you overcome it's cryptic configuration. If you think it's too tricky, try the 0.9 version even though it's pretty old (1.x was a full rewrite) since it looks the same but has a less complicated (less feature rich) setup.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a "Checkbox Treeview", look no further: https://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

I stumbled upon this question when looking for a Checkbox Treeview so I thought I'd post a link - maybe helpful to others out there like myself!

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery Ui** has a **menu** widget which is essentially a tree structure.

http://jqueryui.com/menu/

The first two requirements are meet.
I am not sure about the ability to handle drag and dropped items however.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version is here

http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=drag-drop-folder-tree

its very basic and lack some features like tick selection, different icons for open and close folder etc..

Answer (score 0):

Js Tree is an easy one and you can use it in a form with checkboxes plug in to submit to the server
[enter link description here](https://www.jstree.com/)

https://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Sapling](http://tamerayd.in/jquery-sapling/) gets the job done without requiring you to change the markup.